# Script to append code to form success message is placing image outside of message DIV

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, append, slide

I am using an ajax script to generate text in a success message.  The final part of the process is to add a close image DIV which when clicked should close (slide up) the 'panel' DIV which contains the form and the success message, as happens when the close image is clicked on without sending any message.  You can see the form by clicking on 'contact' in the nav bar on [this page](http://salliannputman.com/test/index.php).

Here is the script that generates the success message:

```
$.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "contact-engine.php",
         data: dataString,
         success: function() {
           $('#contact-form').html("<div id='message-form'></div>");
           $('#message-form').html("<h3>Your message has been submitted successfully!</h3>")
           .hide()
           .fadeIn(2000, function() {
             $('<p style="text-align:center">Thanks for getting in touch. I will get back to you as soon as possible.</p>').appendTo('#message-form').hide().fadeIn(2000, function() {
             $('<p style="text-align:center"><a class="close" href="#"><img src="/images/close.png"></a></p>').appendTo('#message-form').hide().fadeIn(2000);
             });
           });
         }
       });
```

And here is the script that handles the click function on the close button DIV:

```
$(".close").click(function ()
        {
            $("#panel").slideUp("slow");
            $("li#contact").removeClass("current");
    //        $("#contact").removeClass("current");
            $panel.visible = false;
            return false;
        });
```

Could someone please let me know why the close button is outside the DIV and why it won't close the form from the success message?

Thanks,

Nick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested it on the site you link to. The close button is not actually outside of the div, it just appears below the area you want it to show up in. That's because the wrapping `<p>` has a height of 0. And it has a height of 0 because you are floating its contents (the `<a>` tag). Just give that `<p>` a height of `35px` and you'll be fine:

```
$('<p style="text-align:center; height:35px"><a class="close" href="#"><img src="/images/close.png"></a></p>')
```

I'm guessing that the click handler doesn't fire because the `.close` element in question doesn't exist when you try binding the `click` event. Just put all that `$('.close').click(...)` code after the line in which you create the `.close` element:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "contact-engine.php",
  data: dataString,
  success: function() {
    $('#contact-form').html("<div id='message-form'></div>");
    $('#message-form').html("<h3>Your message has been submitted successfully!</h3>")
    .hide()
    .fadeIn(2000, function() {
      $('<p style="text-align:center">Thanks for getting in touch. I will get back to you as soon as possible.</p>').appendTo('#message-form').hide().fadeIn(2000, function() {
        $('<p style="text-align:center"><a class="close" href="#"><img src="/images/close.png"></a></p>').appendTo('#message-form').hide().fadeIn(2000);
        $(".close").click(function () {
          $("#panel").slideUp("slow");
          $("li#contact").removeClass("current");
          //$("#contact").removeClass("current");
          $panel.visible = false;
          return false;
        });
      });    
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: @maxedision  Thanks, changing adding the height to the paragraph works fine, but after adding the `$('.close').click(...)` as you suggest the close button still isn't closing the panel

Comment: You're right, I've updated the code and it should work now. This is something fundamental to JavaScript that you should understand. You can't bind an event to an element that doesn't exist yet. That's essentially what you were doing (and it's what the first version of my code was doing). That's also the reason why you generally see everything wrapped in `$(document).ready()` -- it's to prevent the code from running until all the page elements have been created.

Comment: Furthermore, one of the other people here recommended that you use jQuery's `.live()` method, but you should be aware that that has now been deprecated in favor of the new `.on()` method. However, I have still yet to come across an example of where these methods should be used. While you probably won't notice it in small web apps, they are very inefficient methods. The best approach is to do what I did here -- after the element gets created, bind the event to it.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the `$(".close").click(function() { ... })` method only binds selected elements that currently exist in the DOM.  You will have to use some other means such as:

```
$('#message-form').on("click", ".close", function() {
    $("#panel").slideUp("slow");
    $("li#contact").removeClass("current");
    // $("#contact").removeClass("current");
    $panel.visible = false;
    return false;
});
```

As for the close button being outside the div, I'm not quite sure which div you mean and exactly what you're seeing.  I would suggest cleaning up your AJAX as follows:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "contact-engine.php",
    data: dataString,
    success: function() {
        $('#contact-form').html("<div id='message-form'></div>");
        $('#message-form')
            .hide()
            .html("<h3>Your message has been submitted successfully!</h3>")
            .append('<p style="text-align:center">Thanks for getting in touch. I will get back to you as soon as possible.</p>')
            .append('<p style="text-align:center"><a class="close" href="#"><img src="/images/close.png"></a></p>')
            .fadeIn(2000);
    }
});
```

Unless of course you do intend to have things fade in progressively.  Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, Phil.  I tried using your cleaned up ajax code but it broke the script on my form, so something would seem to be awry.

Comment: It looks like I missed a closing `}` for the success function.  I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick jsFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/MRaeq/3/

Everything with you add seems right. but the click event looks like it may need a live handler to be added once the close button is created unless you were already handling it

Comment: Thanks William, that fixes the closing of the panel DIV

Answer (score 0):

I put an example (with changes) in here: http://jsfiddle.net/MarkSchultheiss/bUWh4/

Not really that pretty, but you should be able to extract what you need, and the click on the button works by changing to .on()